# MySQL query failed to retrieve data...or something like that

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-num-rows

I have just looked at a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPW-Lpil5CU) on how to create a custom database. I have tried to implement this into my site. 
However, obviously, it isn't working...

I get an error 'Query failed: ' and nothing more from the following code.

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to database"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name");

$terms = explode(" ", $search);
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each){
$i++;
if ($i == 1)
  $query .= "keywords LIKE '%each%' ";
else
   $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%each%' ";
}

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br   />\n$sql"); 

if ($numrows > 0)
   while($row = mysqlfetch_ASSOC($query)){
   $id = $row['id'];
   $title = $row['title'];
   $description= $row['description'];
   $keywords = $row['keywords'];
   $link = $row['link'];

   echo '<h2><a href="$link">$title</a><h2>
   $description<br/><br/>';
   }
else 

   echo "No results found";

   //disconnect
   mysql_close();

?>
```

To be honest, I only understand about 70% of that and have no idea. The database is connected properly and functions. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG???

mysql_num_rows was causing problems before but after putting a space inbetween WHERE'' and the closing quotation mark, it left me here.

Comment: what happens if you move the WHERE, infront of 'keywords like'....does your query return everything?

Comment: Move your `or die(... mysql_error()...)` to the query `$query = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br   />\n$sql");` This is where you will get the error message that you need. Where are you declaring `$search`?

Comment: So, I changed $search to $my search which is what it was supposed to be. $mysearch is declared in a global file and simply gets the input from the search box. I may be getting somewhere as now, when i type in a keyword in the database, it gives '$title' and '$description' as plain text and not their variable counter-parts

Comment: GREAT! I done what you said (move the or die thingy) and it works. I just need to be able to display the variable as an actual variable and not $title or $description in plain text. I can't do echo $title; as I need to give it a href value which is a variable also

Comment: Do you think it would be wirth posting that in another question as I've had a look online and none of the methods I've come across work

Comment: GOT IT!!!     echo '<br/><br/><div style="color:#444; font-size:200%; text-align:center"><a href="'. $link .'">' . $title . '</a></div>
    <div style="color:#09f; font-size:130%; text-align:center" ">' . $description . '</div>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off....you need to include the $each to include the variable...not just each...

```
$query .= "WHERE keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ";
```

Also....Move the WHERE infront of keywords, so that if a user enters nothing into the search...they will query everything...otherwise if they enter nothing, it will break...

```
 $terms = explode(" ", $search);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM search ";

  if(!empty($terms)){

  foreach ($terms as $each){
   $i++;
     if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "WHERE keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ";
      else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Now I'm getting 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqlfetch_assoc()'

Comment: Now there's a problem with the variables...It's just displaying the variables as text '$title' and '$description'

Comment: It's obviously just not recognising them as php variables but, instead, just plain text

Comment: Here's an example search query just for reference http://screencap.net/f/b3c2e13e.png

Comment: Also, it does work if I simply put echo $title; echo $description; etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the problem, but, shouldn't this:

```
$query .= "keywords LIKE '%each%' ";
```

be this instead:

```
$query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ";
```

It is treating each as text and not as the string in the loop.

(same goes two lines below)